# Solving sin 3x * cos 3x = sin 2x

Tags: trigonometry

So we're learning trigonometry in school and I need a little help how to solve a equation.

So I got the following equation:

$\sin 3x * cos 3x = sin 2x $

so I used the formula

$\sin a * cosb = 1/2( sin(a+b) + sin(a-b) ) $

but don't know how to continue. Here is my solution so far:

$\ sin 3x * cos 3x = sin 2x $

$\ 1/2( sin(3x+3x) + sin(3x-3x) ) = sin 2x $

$\ 1/2( sin(6x) + sin(0) ) = sin 2x $

$\ 1/2 sin 6x = sin 2x $

What is my next step to continue? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\sin 3x .\cos 3x=\sin2x\\
\Rightarrow 2\sin 3x .\cos 3x=2\sin2x\\
\Rightarrow\sin6x=2\sin2x\\
\Rightarrow\sin3(2x)=2\sin2x\\
\Rightarrow 3\sin2x-4\sin^32x=2\sin2x\\
\Rightarrow 3\sin2x-4\sin^32x-2\sin2x=0\\
\Rightarrow \sin2x-4\sin^32x=0\\
\Rightarrow \sin2x(1-4\sin^22x)=0\\
$$
Then $$\sin 2x=0$$ and $$\sin2x=\pm \frac{1}{2}$$

Comment: Thanks! I will use that, but is there any way to continue my solution. PP: how 2 sin 3x* cos 3x became sin 6x?

Comment: Using $\sin 2x=2\sin x\cos x$. If you multiply by 2 on both sides of your last equation will be the same as the third line of my works....

Comment: @Deepsy Your last step is Rana's 3rd step, so you can replace the first two steps with the work in your question.

Comment: Whenever we have $\sin^2mx$ or $\cos^2mx$ we can use $$\displaystyle \cos2y=2\cos^2y-1=1-2\sin^2y$$